# Laptop suddenly gets turned off at charging 45%

Tags: windows-8, laptop, battery, acer-aspire, ultrabook

Mine is acer aspire S7-392-9890 model ultrabook and It is very new. I just received it yesterday! I am totally happy with it except the charging.

It really put me in shock when it first turned off at 45% charging. I thought that battery might not be charged properly as I just received it yesterday, but no! the same thing happened twice thereafter. When I turn it back on, it either doesn't turn on (due to battery low) or it shows 5% charging dying to get charged.

I couldn't figure it out why it happens. I am really worried because it is a new laptop and also whether it is going to get fixed or not.

Any suggested solutions from anyone please? that would be great. Thanks.

**EDIT**: Okay to check if the battery is faulty, I have unplugged the charging at 32% to see if it dies back again but no, it worked and didn't turn off? I have no idea why is it happening. Any other solutions please?

Comment: Sounds like you got a defective battery. Try leaving it plugged in overnight to charge. If that doesn't fix it, return it to be fixed.

Comment: Yesterday I charged it up until it reached 100% and found it again turned off around 45%.

Comment: I have had a few machines that didn't report accurate battery life. Sometimes they power down at very low percentages, sometimes reasonably high. I think its more a function of a bad battery, you could test this theory by timing the battery life if you had an accurate measure of how much power the laptop is using over time. Just return it.

Answer (score 1):

Take it back. There's no reason to keep a laptop that is effectively dead on arrival.

Based on your edit, I would suggest charging it fully (more than 2 hours should be enough) then unplugging it and letting it run down by setting the power options to not turn off the screen, go to sleep, etc.

Either it was teething issues and it doesn't happen again, or the battery is simply not reliable and should be taken back. I would generally opt for the early life failure, as it's likely to be replaced on the spot instead of being "repaired" (assuming you have this particular consumer protection in your country).

Comment: Please see my edit